# Substitute or replacing value in MySQL query from another column

Tags: mysql, null, substitution

How can I substitute or replace `NULL` values in MySQL query to the value that I need?

If null or coleasce or with case or with if?
I can't get it work.

Example is in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac035)

- First and second row:

  - Third column: sum of all products;
  - Fourth column: active products;
  - Fifth column: inactive products.
- Third and forth row:

  - Third column: sum of all products;
  - Fourth column: active products;
  - Fifth column: inactive products (`NULL` values => need the `0` value).
- Fifth and sixth row:

  - Third column: sum of all products;
  - Fourth column: active products (`NULL` values => need the `0` value);
  - Fifth column: inactive products (`NULL` values => need the value from the third column).

If I get the `NULL` value for inactive products I need to replace it with `0`, but when I get `NULL` value in active product, I need to replace it with `0` and in inactive column replace the `NULL` value with the value from third column.

No `UPDATE` or `INSERT` functions, because this is a MySQL view.

---

Basiclly what I need is:

```
if active <> 0 and inactive <> 0
then 'no value change'

if active <> 0 and inactive = null
then inactive = 0

if active = null
then active = 0 and inactive = product_sum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use an *expression* in place of a column name in the `SELECT` list.

If we want the SQL be portable and ANSI standards compliant, we can use a `CASE` expression. For example:

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN t.inactive_product IS NULL
           THEN t.product_sum
           ELSE t.inactive_product 
         END AS inactive_product
    FROM ... t
```

An equivalent result can be obtained (more concisely) using the `COALESCE` function:

```
  SELECT COALESCE(t.inactive_product,t.product_sum) AS inactive_product
       , COALESCE(t.active_product,0)               AS active_product
    FROM ... t
```

Most databases, including MySQL, provide functions that extend the SQL standard.

The same result can be achieved in MySQL with the convenient `IFNULL` function.

```
  SELECT IFNULL(t.inactive_product,t.product_sum) AS inactive_product
       , IFNULL(t.active_product,0)               AS active_product
    FROM ... t
```

**FOLLOWUP:**

To me it looks like the following condition tends to be true in the data, or at least in the result we want returned:

```
 product_sum = active_product + inactive_product
```

I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT ... 
     , t.product_sum
     , IFNULL(t.active_product,0) AS active_product
     , IFNULL(t.inactive_product,t.product_sum-IFNULL(t.active_product,0))
       AS inactive_product
 FROM ... t
```

Comment: sorry for stupid question. is it possible to have multiple case when in query? that´s the only thing that i not tried